# How to evenly distribute points along the curve y=1/x?

Tags: functions

How would I find the (2d) co-ordinates of n points on the on the curve y=1/x such that the arc lengths between consecutive points is equal (assuming the co-ordinates of the 1st and nth points are known) ?

I found this formula for the arc length: https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-arc-length-of-f-x-1-x-on-x-in-1-2

Steps:

1. Calculate the line curve length between the 1st and nth point, call the length L.
2. Divide L by n - 1 to get s.
3. Solve for each intermediate point so that it is a length s from the previous point.

(It is the third step I am unsure of, as it will involve solving an equation with an infinite sum, assuming the use / modification of the formula linked above).

Comment: Well, you presumably aren’t going to start at $x=0$, so use the integral formula for the arc length over the entire $x$ range and then iteratively find each of the intermediate $x$ values so that you get equal arc lengths.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar I'll try your approach, maybe the calculation will simplify.

Comment: The series approximation for $\sqrt{(1+1/x^4)}$ is a clever idea. It will work if the lower bound of your range is$ >1$. You would have to embed this series inside a Newton-Raphson iterative algorithm.

Comment: I decided not to bother with this problem. What I did instead was to look at x, rather than 1/x, and divide that into equal sized divisions over the entire range of x.

Comment: How about distributing the x points so that the areas under the curve between strips are all equal?

Comment: See my answer below based on the comment above

Answer (score 1):

If you use the criterion of equal areas under the curve in each segment, then your distribution for $x \in [a,b]$ with $N$ intervals follows the rule

$$
x_k = \Bigg(\frac{b}{a}\Bigg)^{1/N}x_{k-1} ,\hspace{01cm} k=0\cdots N
$$

with $x_0=a$

For  $a=1$, $b=2$, and $N=10$, the distributions looks like this:

[image]